# LibreOffice calc: how to filter one or several tags in a multiple tags column

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have libreoffice-calc file like this:

```
books   author      tags
Book 1  Author 1    ghost; romance; france
Book 2  Author 2    romance; mystery
Book 3  Author 3    biographie; england
Book 4  Author 4    history; england
Book 5  Author 5    children’s book; ghost
```

There is a column called "tags" with multiple tags in it, separate by a semi colon (but it could be anything).

I would like to be able to filter on specific tag present on the "tags" column. And I would like to be able to select several tag in one filter.

For example on my file: if I select "ghost" on my filter, the list will return

```
books   author      tags
Book 1  Author 1    ghost; romance; france
Book 5  Author 5    children’s book; ghost
```

Or if I filter "biographie", I will have "Book 3" only as a result.

```
books   author      tags
Book 3  Author 3    biographie; england
```

With multiple tag selected: if I select "ghost" and "mystery" on my filter, the list will return:

```
books   author      tags
Book 1  Author 1    ghost; romance; france
Book 2  Author 2    romance; mystery
Book 5  Author 5    children’s book; ghost
```

I know I can do that with advanced filters and regular expressions but, if I do not mistake, I need to re-create an the advanced filter every time I need to change the tags filtered. I want to make this list public so casual users (without any knowledge about libreoffice calc) can make their own research by tags without having to go in the trouble to create a new advanced filter. Is there a way to have a only a simple drop-down menu on my "tags" column ?

Comment: No, you can't (at least not for selecting parts of cell contents).It may work with LO Base, but this would require quite a lot work...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be kind of possible now, but possibly "simple" only if You search for one tag at a time (You can use "Standard Filter" and a regular expression while using this method I believe, but considering what You wrote I assume that's not he solution You're looking for).

[Video presenting the solution](https://imgur.com/a/GpJP8CH).

1. Select the column You'd like to filter the data by.
2. Select in the menu bar: Data → AutoFilter.
   2.1. "Agree" if the "The range does not contain column headers.
   Do you want the first line to be used as column header?" prompt appear.
3. Click on a triangle that should appear in the cell in the first row of the selected column ([image])
4. In the "Search item..." input box write down the specific tag You want.
5. Select "OK".

It's not perfect as if You'd have tags like "england" and "medival england" and search for "england" the other one may be included by default too.